# 'Abp.Zero.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' Method 'Get' does not have an implementation

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

```
System.TypeLoadException:"Method 'Get' 
in type 'Abp.DynamicEntityProperties.DynamicEntityPropertyValueStore' 
from assembly 'Abp.Zero.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
does not have an implementation."
```

I'm using the latest version 6.0.0 AspNetCore-MVC-template.

Is the problem caused by the "Abp.Zero.Common"?

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by dependency conflicts during the transition from "Abp" version 6.0.0 to 6.2.0. In the process of using version 6.0.0 without upgrading, The "Abp" library that the "Abp.AutoMapper(6.0.0)" library relies on automatically becomes version 6.2.0.. After I upgraded the "Abp" version to 6.2.0, this problem was solved.